# Laravel failed to open stream

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

**UPDATE:** I managed to resolve the issue by completely removing the vendor directory, and re-running the `composer install` command. I still don't know what was the actual cause of this beahviour, but at least it's working now.

---

I've been tasked to troubleshoot and improve an application written in Laravel.

Since I almost always worked in Codeigniter, my knowledge of Laravel boils down to "I know what it is and where to download it from" :)

So, the application fails with the the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  Uncaught ErrorException: require(\Repos\PermissionRepo.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in \wwwroot\app\Repos\PermissionRepo.php:5
```

the PermissionRepo file  looks like this:

```
2: namespace Wckphma\Repos;
3:
4: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
5: use Wckphma\User;
```

the seemingly missing Wckphma\User declaration file does exist, and the beginning of the file looks like this:

```
namespace Wckphma;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Wckphma\Repos\GroupRepo;
use Wckphma\Repos\PermissionRepo;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
****
```

It cannot be the file permissions, as in pure desperation I gave all the user  read/write permissions to all files throughout.

Any ideas, what this might be?

Comment: Have you downloaded your project completely ?

Comment: try runnig  command "composer dump"

Comment: Yes I downloaded the entire project. I get the logins screen, and I can login successfully, but once I get to the supposedly user home page that's when the error occurs. I run the "composer dump" as well but nothing changed